# How to add MD5 to the name of apk with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For our naming convention, we need to add in the end of the apk name the MD5 of the file.
I tried to use this fun

```
static def generateMD5(final file) {
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
file.withInputStream(){is->
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]
    int read = 0
    while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
byte[] md5sum = digest.digest()
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum)
return bigInt.toString(16).padLeft(32, '0')
```

and in the application variant task

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.outputFileName = "MyApp v${variant.versionName}-${generateMD5(output.outputFile)}.apk"
    }
}
```

The problem is that the APK file is not created in this task, so where i should modify the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i did it with jenkins with shell script. thanks!